# websocket-rails cant receive broadcasted response in the browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, websocket, passenger

I'm using `websocket_rails` and the frontend is on angular.

On my local machine, im able to subscribe a client to the websocket channel and also able to get the response back to the browser that was dispatched by the server. But on staging this seems to be not working.

I'm using nginx and phusion passenger on staging and websocket with redis on standalone mode.

`var dispatche1  = new WebSocketRails('mydomain.com:5000/websocket');` to create a dispatcher and

```
   `var channel = dispatche1.subscribe('my_channgel');
      channel.bind('success', function (resp) {
      var response = JSON.parse(resp);
      console.log('here')
    });`
```

to subscribe to the channel.

Back on my controller I do this

`WebsocketRails[:my_channel].trigger "success", {:message => "HI", :user => 8}.to_json`

And again in my logs I could see this

`[2015-03-20 04:13:35.915] [Channel] [my_channel] "{\"message\":\"HI\",\"user\":14}"`

So I dont seem to be able to get the issue.

Here is how I have configured my servers

Phusion passenger on port 5014, 5015. Thin with redis (websocket standalone server) on port 5000.

Has anyone been through this issue ?

Let me know if you need more information. I could also post my nginx config if required.

PS: This is tested on my local machine with websocket on standalone mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! It was a mistake in my configuration. 
I had pointed the websocket server to 5000 but in my configuration i had mentioned a different port.

Issue solved.